# Ruby on Rails Select2 form not returning params ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am having trouble getting the params output from the following form. I am using Select2 and collection_select to create a text auto-complete drop dropdown, that populated items to be selected from a table column.

Submit does not get back any params? How do I fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
</script>



        <%= form_tag do  %>
            <select class="js-example-basic-single">
                <option value= <% collection_select(:id, :id, @items, :items_id, :items_id) %>
                </option>
            </select>
            <%= submit_tag 'Submit',class:"btn-primary btn-lg"%></br>
        <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on code you have provided, it looks like you are creating select tag in options which is causing issue.

Based on what I understand it should look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
</script>

<%= form_tag do  %>
  <% collection_select(:id, :id, @items, :items_id, :items_id,{},{class: 'js-example-basic-single'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit',class:"btn-primary btn-lg"%></br>
<%end%>
```

You can get details about `collection_select` from official documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: I have done the above. It does not display as expected, it just diaplays a regular collection select drop down ? I am not sure what I have to do to get this to work. Is it something to do with maybe naming that class before it is called inside the embedded ruby ?

Comment: It was a bootstrap issue, The code you have provided works correctly ! Thanks so much, really appreciate it. For anyone else using remeber to add this "*= require select2-bootstrap" to the application CSS!